# How to Post Tags on Wordpress using Joeblogs.dll

Tags: c#, wordpress, xml-rpc, joeblogs

I'm coding a class for posting on wp blogs and I'm using Joeblogs.dll. What I cannot find in the Post struct (or anywhere else) is how to create tags with the blog post.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: You may add a reference for your `Joeblogs.dll` I never read the name.

Comment: I did, the thing is that there is no method for adding tags.

Comment: This is wrong you just have too less reputation to do that. Anyway what does that dll do? If I google for that this question is the match number 4.

Comment: I'm talking about wordpress tags as in when posting about "C#" you add additional keywords like "visual studio", "programming" etc. Joeblogs.dll contains a wordpress wrapper facilitating the communication with a wp blog via xml-rpc.

Comment: Do you use the DLL from [CodePlex](http://joeblogs.codeplex.com/)? This version is apparently very old and there have been some changes. You should check out the version on [GitHub](https://github.com/alexjamesbrown/JoeBlogs) which is more recent and has the capabilities to add Tags (you have to build the DLL by yourself though).

Comment: You're right. I built the DLL from the GitHub source and it had everything. Thanks, vstm! And I've been researching for weeks.